# I get an error as part of my matlab scripts

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a piece of matlab code that does some sql queries and such. I've been getting an error here and there. But despite the error, everything seem to have completed, so I am wondering what's causing the error messages and what it means. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you!

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL Exception : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.emulateExecuteBatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatchUpdate(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: We would appreciate the matlab source code.

Comment: You may edit the title to make it more clear, like what kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is not harmful, and it won't always happen, right? Then it is likely due to java methods are not synced with a model by the time they run. There are possibly several solutions. One is to use javaObjectEDT to wrap up java object if possible:

```
javaControl = javaObjectEDT(javaControl);
```

The other method is to add some delay after javaControl property is changed.

```
javaControl.doSomething();
pause(0.05); drawnow;
```

For detail explanation, check [this by Yair Altman](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handling-red-java-console-errors).